# How to show this series converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I found the following exercise in a book about analysis.

> Given that
> $$a_n>0,\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}a_n<+\infty,\alpha>0,\beta>0,\text{and}{\ }\alpha+\beta>1$$
> show that the series converge:
> $$\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{a_n^{\alpha}}{n^\beta}<+\infty$$

Before talking about this question,I have met a similar question:

> Given that
> $$a_n>0,\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}a_n<+\infty$$
> show that the series converge:
> $$\forall\delta>0,\text{we have that}\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^\frac{1+\delta}{2}}<+\infty$$

I have sovled this problem through the Cauchy Inequality like this：
$$\sum\limits^{k}_{n=1}\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^\frac{1+\delta}{2}}<\sum\limits^{k}_{n=1}a_n\sum\limits^{k}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^{1+\delta}}<M$$
since $S_k=\sum\limits^{k}_{n=1}\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^\frac{1+\delta}{2}}$ is monotone and bounded,so we have proved this proposition.

Now back to the first question,at first sight I want to use the same skill to prove this proposition. I guess that there exists a interger $N$,for all $n>N$, we have：
$$\frac{a_n^{\alpha}}{n^\beta}<\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^{\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}}}$$
so I can prove it through the Cauchy Inequality:
$$S_k=\sum\limits^{k}_{n=1}\frac{a_n^{\alpha}}{n^\beta}<\sum\limits^{k}_{n=N+1}\frac{a_n^{\alpha}}{n^\beta}+\sum\limits^{N}_{n=1}\frac{a_n^{\alpha}}{n^\beta}<\sum\limits^{k}_{n=N+1}\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^{\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}}}+c\leq\sum\limits^{k}_{n=N+1}a_n\sum\limits^{k}_{n=N+1}\frac{1}{n^{\alpha+\beta}}+c<M$$
where：
$$c=\sum\limits^{N}_{n=1}\frac{a_n^{\alpha}}{n^\beta}$$
But actually, I can't prove my guess.Am I using the wrong method?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved in a similar way if you are aware of [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) $-$ a generalization of Cauchy inequality $-$ which states that:

$$\sum \left| a_n b_n\right| \leq \left(\sum {a_n}^p\right)^{1/p}\left(\sum {b_n}^q\right)^{1/q},$$

for $p>0$, $q>0$, $1/p + 1/q = 1$. (Awfully similar to the current setup of your question)

**Hint:** Assume $0<\alpha<1$ (why?), and try identifying the left side with

$$\sum {a_n}^\alpha \frac{1}{n^\beta}\leq \cdots.$$

Comment: It’s easy to talk about the problem when $\alpha\geq{1}$. I think the reason why $0< \alpha<1$ is that we should let $1<p,q$. Thanks to your hint, I have totally solved the problem.